# Differential Equation Question for a separation of variables problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling with the differential equation $yln(x)dx/dy = ((y+1)/x)^2$

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: multiply by $x^2$ and divide by $y$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

It can be written as

$$x^2\ln (x)dx=\frac {(y+1)^2}{y}dy $$

$$=(y+2+\frac {1}{y})dy $$

use by parts integration for the left side.

Comment: assumeing $y$ isn't identically 0.